# Why I cannot answer some questions in askubuntu.com/unanswered (no answer-field)?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I just joined Ask Ubuntu and wanted to answer one question at https://askubuntu.com/unanswered but there is no answer field to enter my answer. Why?

I have 1 reputation and I tried to contribute to raise it so I can unlock some activities but I don't understand why I can't do that. One example from today is [20.04 - Google Chrome Display Glitches after wake up](https://askubuntu.com/q/1272864/944289) (an unanswered question where I cannot see any answering field to write into).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know that such thing exists!

Comment: Ok I now see that I need a reputation 10 to answer this example in my post.

Comment: I have unprotected the question so it can be answered by anyone (the Community bot will protect it again if it gets another answer that is deleted)

Answer (score 4):

As the page says in the bottom, you must earn 10 reputation points before you can answer such a question.

> [image: Highly active question. Earn 10 reputation in order to answer this question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity.]

This measure is usually put on questions which got many answers in the past that were later deleted because of their low quality.

There are still lots of ordinary questions you can answer freely even with 1 reputation!